# Script is not replacing the prefix of filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to replace the prefix of all files in the directory with another prefix (renaming).

This is my script

```
# Script to rename the files
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1*;
do
    mv $file `echo $file | sed -e 's/^$1/$2/'`;
done
```

Upon executing the script with

```
rename.sh BIT SIT
```

I get the following errors

```
mv: `BITfile.h' and `BITFile.h' are the same file
mv: `BITDefs.cpp' and `BITDefs.cpp' are the same file
mv: `BITDefs.h' and `BITDefs.h' are the same file
```

Seems like `sed` is treating `$1` and `$2` as the same value, but when I print those variables on another line it shows that they are different.

Comment: Don't forget to accept one of the solutions below if they helped you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roman Newaza says, you can use `"` instead of `'` to tell Bash that you want variables to be expanded. However, in your case, it would be safest to write:

```
for file in "$1"* ; do
    mv -- "$file" "$2${file#$1}"
done
```

so that weird characters in filenames, or in your script parameters, cannot cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace the **prefix** of all files in a directory.

```
for file in "$1"*;
do
  mv ${file} ${file/#$1/$2}
done
```

Comment: You want to use `"$1"*` to be able to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: It's fine with this particular example, but it's probably a good idea to double-quote both arguments to `mv` in case of whitespace in filenames etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead:

```
# ...
mv "$file" `echo $file | sed -e "s/^$1/$2/"`
# ...
```

And learn [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't use double quotes, the variables won't expand.

I will rather use this

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1*;
do
   mv "$file" "$1${file:${#2}}"
done
```

where

```
${file:${#2}
```

means substring, from length of the argument 2 to the end